# Scheme nested lambda function

Tags: function, lambda, nested, scheme, sicp

I am a beginner in Scheme. I found this question in MIT exam 1 for SICP lecture.

**What's the value and type for –**

```
((lambda (a) (lambda (b) (+ (sqrt a) (sqrt b)))) 5)
```

I am having a hard time understanding how this function works. I am really confused about the parameter `b`. Only `5` is passed as a parameter to the outer lambda function, then what value does `b` take for the inner lambda function?

I tried running this function in mit-scheme but the resulting value gets incremented each time it's run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that only the outer lambda form is applied to the argument 5. Then it returns its body with `a` replaced with 5, so it would return

```
(lambda (b) (+ (sqrt 5) (sqrt b)))
```

which is itself a function. This could later be applied to another argument, to produce an actual numeric value.

Comment: When i run the code in mit-scheme i am getting result as follows `Value 13: #[compound-procedure 13] `.  What is value 13 here?  When i run the code again the value gets incremented as  `Value 14:#[compound-procedure 14]`. Why does this happen?

Comment: It sounds like those might just be unique IDs generated for each procedure.